# Excel - How do I look up multiple cells from a single reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, lookup

I'm looking to somehow look up a certain amount of cells from a single reference and return them in the same order in another workbook.

For example, say I have 5 different SKU codes (these aren't repeated in the column) and each SKU code has 10 cells of data in it's row with different values.

I'm looking to take the 10 cells relating to that SKU and basically paste them along side the same SKU in a different workbook. However, the SKU's on the other workbook are not in the same order so I'm guessing a lookup is required?

I've included an example which hopefully makes it clearer. I'd like excel to look up the SKU and return the corresponding data for weeks 1 - 10. Column headers will be in the same order on both workbooks however the SKU's are in different order.

[image: Sheet 1 example]

[image: Sheet 2 example]

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Say sheet1 is like:

[image]

and we want the data associated with sku 11111.  All we need is the row number and then we can use `INDEX` for each column

in Sheet2 **A1** enter 11111 and in **A2** enter:

```
=MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)
```

Then in **B2** enter:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet2!$A2)
```

and copy across:

[image]